# Mod rewrite rule to serve folder.php when i access /folder/ URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Considering the following file structure:

```
/duplicate/index.php
/duplicate.php
```

I want when I access `/duplicate/` URL to serve `/duplicate.php` if it exists, otherwise fall back on default behaviour and serve `/duplicate/index.php`.

Rule must work with subfolders on any number of levels (e.g. `/a/b/c/d/e/f/`)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1.php [L]
```

`$1` is a backreference to the captured group in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*, ie. the URL-path less the trailing slash. The *condition* then checks that the file exists before rewriting the URL. If it doesn't exist then it falls back to "default behaviour".